# How to show the animation without exposing the code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

There's an animation done in jQuery within jsfiddle. I do not have a website as of now to "implant" it and share the URL.

I also **can't** give the jsfiddle. So how can I share my animation to the audience without showing the code? Does github or any other facility tools allow locking the code and showing the final product without having a website, yet I could get a URL for the audience to view it?

I regret for the rookie-question in this context as I am still new to web stuff.

---

### EDIT:

jsFiddle shows 3 code windows along the results :html, css, js. My requirement is to only show the results window to the audience and by all means to hide codes and leads via URL to the codes.

Ideal solution demands a results to be shown and URL that is encrypted (at best).

Comment: Yes; it's called jsFiddle.  Why can't you use jsFiddle?  Are you aware that Javascript code is _always_ sent to the client?

Comment: you may compress and symbol obfuscate the js code so in the client source js cannot be readable and interpret in meaning full human readable words

Comment: @SLaks yes I figured out Javascript is sent to the client - as to why there's a need for enabling Javascripts in the browsers. In my question I have stated about jsFiddle and why I do not want to use it. The ideal would be - having a repository I could just give the URL to animation window.

Comment: you may create a video clip of the animation and play it in a page, unless otherwise your code is exposed

Comment: You have not stated why you don't want to use jsFiddle.  Until you give a reason why not, jsFiddle remains the correct answer to this question.

Comment: Create `.gif` ? See this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334820/css-and-jquery-animation

Comment: @SLaks do you know a way you can make jsfiddle to show only the output window and hide all other 3 coding windows? (html, js, css) I have a requirement : only the final output window. By right it should be a web page. Since creating a web page, hosting, isn't an option at the moment I am looking for alternatives to share the jquery based animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question you could try the following:

1. Copy your jsfiddle text to a single index.html file (use script tag for js and style tag for css)
2. Install node.js on your development computer
3. Install a tool to obfuscate your file (e.g. `npm install -g munch`)
4. Obfuscate your file (see instructions https://www.npmjs.org/package/munch)
5. Host your file somewhere (could be a github project page with a repository containing only the obfuscated file - although its not really the point of github).
6. Send url to audience

Someone could still reverse engineer your animation but it would take a lot of effort and would probably be easier to write from scratch.

However, perhaps you would be better off doing a screen cast and sharing a youtube link.

Comment: I am worried about the quality of the youtube link? I wish if there was a way to share jsfiddle or codeacademy or github work by just showing the output and keep the skeleton as skeleton (behind the walls).

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're asking for is simply not possible.
JavaScript is a client-side scripting language and is interpreted by the browser of the viewer of your animation. This means that, by the nature of the language, the viewer needs the code loaded in his/her browser to view your animation.

More in-depth information can be found here: http://computer.howstuffworks.com/javascript.htm

The only way you could achieve your goal is by screen capturing the animation, but that would, of course, only work with static animations.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've clarified your question, we can give you an actual answer.

Click the Share button in jsFiddle's toolbar (after saving your fiddle) to get a link to the result only.

Comment: Wow no wonder you were trying to get me to the "point" :D it's that simple. However there's a tricky part. [e.g.](http://jsfiddle.net/b954W/embedded/result/) User can always be *smart* enough to go into the code view by simply using the URL. So I was trying to create a `tinyurl`, but not much luck. So is there a way to encrypt the URL of the result?

Comment: @bonCodigo: There is no point in doing that; users can _always_ view source.

Comment: I created SVG file with required components and added jQuery animation codes to call those. I think I pretty much achieved what I wanted. Further, I had to create my own web page to add the stuff in. And I tried out with few people and notice that they can't actually download my SVG file. So that's good enough. =) I would have accepted your answer, but I want to support the @chriskelly for showing another way to do it.

Comment: You can trivially download the SVG from the dev tools.

Comment: Well then, what else... this makes me curious though. What about those mobile apps convert from web/js html to mobile? Are they lack secrity as well?

Comment: @bonCodigo: It is fundamentally impossible to make the client run code without letting the client see that code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want users to see your code do this in your html code:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

Comment: I editted the question. My current code is in a jsfiddle. Does your code help in anyway to achieve what I need?

Comment: get a free web hosting put your code and put the code i wrote on your html and you have a site where you can send to your friends yet they can't watch the source jQuery code

Comment: disabling context menu will not stop users clicking on other browser menus. Ctrl-U to view source will still work.

Comment: @garrytowel well didn't we skip the obvious "get a free web hosting put your code..."?